# How to specify frontend for wsdl2java in a pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, cxf, pom.xml, wsdl2java

I found [this great tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656246/1864054) about adding `-fe jaxws21` to the wsdl2java command to have it generate jaxws 2.1 compliant code instead of 2.2, but Maven's `pom.xml` doesn't seem to like this addition when placed like this:

```
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java -fe jaxws21</goal>
            </goals>
```

What is the correct way of specifying a frontend for wsdl2java that's used in a pom.xml?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using cxf-codegen-plugin, you can add the arguments in extraargs element:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>...</wsdl>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Source: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: You can also do <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>

Comment: Instead of <wsdlOptions>, I have used <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlRoot>. Now How shall I provide <extraarg> with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<frontEnd>` inside `<wsdlOption>` or `<defaultOption>`. The latter is helpful, if you include multiple WSDLs and specified `<wsdlRoot>`:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <defaultOptions>
                <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
            </defaultOptions>
            <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
            <includes>
                <include>*.wsdl</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement @fishbone's and @tafit3's answers, see also [Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141902/could-not-find-jaxws21-frontend-within-classpath) because it looks like `frontend` was added in a minor cxf version.

I tried their answers but only got things working after upgrading cxf-codegen-plugin to 2.3.11