# Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, cxf

For various reasons I need to try out the jaxws21 frontent in my build. So I followed the tip on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113078/1864054), adding to the wsdl options:

```
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
```

But my build complains:

> Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath

How do I resolve this?

BTW, my pom.xml includes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Could this be the culprit? If so, which version should I be changing it to?

**UPDATE:** I tried changing (in that dependency) `2.2.8` to `2.1` but I am still getting this same exact error.

Comment: What version of CXF plugin are you using?

Comment: @DanielKulp `2.2.7` (because the latest & greatest 2.5.2 breaks things in this legacy system that I inherited)

Comment: But... [this post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201203.mbox/%3C2771153.DNJ5AMHGsK@dilbert.dankulp.com%3E) indicates that the `-fe` flag *"was added long after CXF 2.3.1"*. Do I really need to try again 2.5.2 and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. [That](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201203.mbox/%3C2771153.DNJ5AMHGsK@dilbert.dankulp.com%3E) was it. The `-fe` flag is only accepted from CXF **2.3.3** and higher (I was using 2.2.7)