# Unable to execute wsdl2java with maven

Tags: maven, grails, wsdl2java

I want to execute wsdl2java with maven but I have the following build failure :

```
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (default) @ mogopay ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2:jar
[INFO] Configured Artifact: javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.2:jar
[INFO] Copying jaxb-api-2.2.jar to c:\Users\EBIZNEXT\git\mogopay-core\mogopay\target\endorsed\jaxb-api-2.2.jar
[INFO] Copying jaxws-api-2.2.jar to c:\Users\EBIZNEXT\git\mogopay-core\mogopay\target\endorsed\jaxws-api-2.2.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (copy-tomcat-resources) @ mogopay ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:2.4.2:wsdl2java (CXF Payline) @ mogopay ---
[INFO] Running wsdl2java in fork mode...
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\EBIZNEXT\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-679212\cxf-codegen5225275003143491559.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:30.351s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 22 18:28:57 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.4.2:wsdl2java (CXF Payline) on project mogopay:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
[ERROR] at
   ...
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required()
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1954)
[ERROR] at com.sun.codemodel.TypedAnnotationWriter.invoke(TypedAnnotationWriter.java:107)
[ERROR] ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\java.exe" -Djava.endorsed.dirs=c:\Users\EBIZNEXT\git\mogopay-core\mogopay\target/endorsed -jar
 C:\Users\EBIZNEXT\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-679212\cxf-codegen5225275003143491559.jar C:\Users\EBIZNEXT\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-679212\cxf-w2j3628405823287
641812args
```

This project is built in grails 2.0.3. It seems that the problem comes from Jaxb because the current version in grails uses jaxb-api-2.1 while the project needs jaxb 2.2. I have updated my pom as it has been suggested from this answer : [Set Java Compliance Level in CXF wsdl2java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654534/set-java-compliance-level-in-cxf-wsdl2java) and also here : [Example 7 - Using JAXB/JAX-WS 2.2 with Java 6](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html). But when I execute maven command : `mvn clean install`, I get the error above.

Here is my pom (I removed the unimportant parts):

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${project.build.directory}/endorsed</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

         <plugins>
             ...
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
                ...
               <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>once</fork>
                <additionalJvmArgs>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${project.build.directory}/endorsed</additionalJvmArgs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>CXF Payline</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/java/wsdl/Payline_DirectPaymentAPI.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>                
         </plugins>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 already includes jaxb 2.2 (actualy 2.2.4-1 as you can see [**here**](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html)), so you don't need to add any dependency to that artifact. If this artifact conflicts with grails 2.0.3 dependencies, try excluding jaxb from grails dependency, maybe grails is happy with jaxb 2.2.

This should be a comment, but I'm begind a proxy that filters javascript and I cannot use comments feature. Sorry for my English to!